# Hive Array<Struct<field1:string, field2:string> equivalent in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a hive table where one of the column is Array
ruleInfoList array<structfield1:string,field2:string,field3:string,field4:string>

I am trying to create a similar DDL in Bigquery but unable to figure out how to do that.
Then I tried inserting the data without creating a table in BigQuery using Java and noticed below schema and I'm not sure what Record is and from where **list and element** got created. Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

RECORD is STRUCT, and REPEATED is ARRAY in BigQuery SQL, the type of your column should be:

```
ruleinfolist STRUCT<list ARRAY<element STRUCT<dataClassCode STRING, dataRuleGroupCode> > >
```

Tip: to see the type of a table column, you can query [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#columns_view), and check the `DATA_TYPE` column.

Comment: So you mean for storing List<Object>, in this case ruleinfolist, i need to create schema like above

Comment: When you load the data into BigQuery with "auto-detect" schema, this is the type you will get (or you have gotten based on your description)

Comment: okay, but in case I want to provide schema upfront, then what should i use to store array of struct?

Comment: The same type. You can use 1 row of data to test what type will be generated instead of speculating.